# Json endpoint circular reference handler HTTP 500 ERROR

Tags: json, symfony, endpoint

Im currently making an json endpoint for objects (tickets).

This is my function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/json/tickets", name="json_tickets")
 */
public function jsonTickets()
{
    $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $tickets = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Ticket::class)->findAll();

    $jsonObject = $serializer->serialize($tickets, 'json', [
        'circular_reference_handler' => function ($object) {
            return $object->getId();
        }
    ]);

    return new Response($jsonObject);
}
```

This is the entity for Tickets

```
    class Ticket
  {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="tickets")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="ticket_responsibility")
     */
    private $responsible;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="tickets")
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $priority;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $status;


----------
```

This function returns HTTP 500 ERROR.
In the dev.log it gets all the right values and shows no error.

I searched for awnsers but couldn't find any right awnsers for this function.

What is wrong in my function that the server returns an error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
$jsonObject = $serializer->serialize($tickets, 'json', [
    'circular_reference_handler' => function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    }
]);
```

Are you sure that you can pass a list as `$tickets` to `serialize()` instead of a single object like `$ticket`?

If you have to return an object list, use

```
return $this->json($data, $status = 200, $headers = [], $context = []);
```

EDIT:

If you need to handle the circular references, you can do it creating a `CircularReferenceHandler.php` class and registering it as a serializer on `framework.yaml`

Comment: Thanks, can I use this documentation for the circular reference handler? [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references)

Comment: Yes! In your case, on the defaultContext, instead of returning
`return $object->getName();`
Return:
`return $object->getId();`